# Period on Period growth for a dynamic measure

Tags: mdx

I wrote an `mdx` script showing period on period growth for Internet Sales Amount, and it all works fine. 
We are using an interface, where you can place a slicer so that user can choose what dimension of date.Calendar he is interested in, i.e.whatever dimension of Date.Calendar the user decides to choose (Quarter, Month, Year) it will correctly look at previous member. Now, im trying to obtain the same for Measure - i.e. i want it to be flexible dependant on what measure the user will choose in the slicer ( i.e. Internet tax Amount).

I cant think of  a way of creating a previous member with measure being flexible...

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount PP] AS
(
[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Prevmember,
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
)
MEMBER [Measures].[Period on Period Grwth %] AS
IIF (
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount PP] = 0,
    'N/A',
    ([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]-[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount PP]) /[Measures].       [Internet Sales Amount PP]
    )
,FORMAT_STRING = "percent"
SELECT
 [Date].[Calendar].[Month] ON ROWS,

 {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
 [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount PP],
 [Measures].[Period on Period Grwth %]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: 'want it to be flexible dependent on what measure the user will choose in the slicer' - by slicer do you mean the `WHERE` clause? Or a drop down in the application front?

Comment: And of course, where do you want to add the flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use SSRS, you can add a parameter to absorb the measure selected in the drop down from front end. We host SSRS in SharePoint environment and this is how we do it.

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Measure Growth PP] AS
(
[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Prevmember,
strtomember('[Measures].'+ @MeasureSelected)
)
MEMBER [Measures].[Period on Period Grwth %] AS
IIF (
    [Measures].[Measure Growth PP] = 0,
    'N/A',
    (strtomember('[Measures].'+ @MeasureSelected)-[Measures].[Measure Growth PP]) /
    [Measures].[Measure Growth PP]
    )
,FORMAT_STRING = "percent"
SELECT
 [Date].[Calendar].[Month] ON ROWS,

 {strtomember('[Measures].'+ @MeasureSelected),
 [Measures].[Measure Growth PP],
 [Measures].[Period on Period Grwth %]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Your script does this: `SELECT Measures.[Internet Tax Amount].PrevMember ON 0 FROM [Adventure Works];` why do you take this approach?

Comment: @Sorav_Agasti, i am looking forward for currentmember solution somehow... previuous measure doesnt really work for me i think....  it should be working as if there was a drop down slcier in the application.

Comment: So whichever measure is selected in the drop down in front end,you want to evaluate the previous measure from the cube? If so, may I know why?

Comment: Nope..... i want to calculate period on period growth for whatever measure gets selected. Previous member relates only to calendar month, not a measure. so in the script that i wrote, the only change would be making current member of Measures. Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks @Sourav, that makes sense... I'll let you know how I get on!

Comment: Unfortunately the tool that we use doesnt recognize   @MeasureSelected..... when you put something in the slicer, the tool puts it into WHERE clause, so not sure how to script it so it recognizes selected measure...

Comment: Hmm. So you mean that whatever you select in front end's silcer automatically is added to the above MDX's `WHERE` clause portion.